# How to scale bootstrap carousel slide in both directions and have a max height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to be able to have my carousel expand to a certain max-height and then not expand on the page further. However, it should still scale the image appropriately, maintaining the aspect ratio, but "crop" the image.

The effect I am looking for is similar to what can be found here: 
https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/carousel/fullscreen.html

As you can see as you change the width of your browswer window, the image scales and as you get to a really wide browser, the image is "zoomed in" on to maintain the aspect ratio. However this example uses the carousel-fullscreen tag. This makes the carousel take up the fullscreen no matter what size the window is. I want to be able to set a hard limit at say max-height: 700px, and then have the same effect with the image still scaling and zooming in when the browser is very large.

I have also tried using the suggestion in other questions to put the image in the div, then use background-image(...) and background-size: cover, but was still unable to get the effect I'm looking for.

Here is my current implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/hildet/yvkcLh1q/2/

If I set a max-height, when it is reached the image is then just stretched in width and the height stops.

```css
/* CSS */

.item img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vw04Buz.jpg" alt="Slide 1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vw04Buz.jpg" alt="Slide 2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Vw04Buz.jpg" alt="Slide 3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Caption Slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

The effect can be seen when you drag the window in and out.

If further clarification is needed on what I'm looking for please let me know.

Comment: I've found that by changing my CSS to .carousel-inner {
  max-height: 300px;
}
.carousel-inner img {
 width: 100%; 
 margin: auto;
}
I get the zooming effect, however now the caption is lost once it expands beyond the max height. It seems the caption is positioned relative to the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various solutions I have found on the internet I was able to come up with a solution to what I was looking for. It turns out it was a very simple solution.

This is the updated CSS that I used:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding: 80px 120px;    
}

.carousel .item {   
    max-height: 300px;
}

.carousel-inner img {   
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    color: #fff !important;  
}

.carousel-caption {
    top: 40%;
}
```

This now has the affect of the image not being stretched when the screen is very wide. Instead the image maintains its ratio and "zooms" in so that some of the bottom of the image is no longer seen. In addition, with this fix I was able to get the caption to stay vertically centered.

Here is an updated Fiddle of the working code: https://jsfiddle.net/hildet/y12b3bxc/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would work for you. If you need any help, please comment!

```
.item img {width: 100%; min-height: 100%;}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;    
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. If I change min-height to max-height: 100vh in .carousel-inner img, it stops the image from growing any larger than the view area which is part of what I want. But the image is still stretched horizontally once it hits the height of 100vh. I"m curious how to make it start to "zoom" in on the image at this point to maintain the aspect ratio and avoid stretching it out?